# BlackBerry - Convert EncodedImage to byte []

Tags: image, graphics, blackberry, arrays, paint

I am using below code where i don't want to use JPEGEncodedImage.encode because it increases the size. So I need to directly convert from EncodedImage to byte array.

```
FileConnection fc= (FileConnection)Connector.open(name);

is=fc.openInputStream();

byte[] ReimgData = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);

EncodedImage encode_image = 
    EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(ReimgData, 0, (int)fc.fileSize());

encode_image = sizeImage(encode_image, (int)maxWidth,(int)maxHeight);

JPEGEncodedImage encoder=JPEGEncodedImage.encode(encode_image.getBitmap(),50);

ReimgData=encoder.getData();

is.read(ReimgData);

HttpMultipartRequest(
                content[0],
                content[1],
                content[2],
                params,
                "image",txtfile.getText(), "image/jpeg", ReimgData
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [EncodedImage.getData()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#getData()):

*public final byte[] getData()*
Returns the encoded data of this image.
**Returns:** A byte array containing the encoded data for this image.
**Since:** JDE 3.7.0